# 2D integration using modified Gauss Hermite/Stratified Sampling

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm a beginner, trying to numerically integrate

$$ \int\int f(x_{1}, x_{2})g(x_{1}, x_{2}) \,dx_{1}dx_{2} $$

where $g$ is the standard 2D normal density function. Seemingly obvious choice would be Gauss Hermite (GH), but I dont like the abscissas produced by , say, $20$ nodes. Too many abscissas are in tails where as I want to have more of them between $\pm3$, because of how the function f is.

Is there a way to modify GH i.e. modify the abscissas and weights for a given number of nodes. If not, then how could I use stratified sampling instead? Because f is computationally intensive, I cant have too many samples (max $100$ for each of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ probably, total $10000$ samples).